# Programmatically clearing all app data (NSUserDefaults in particular)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have an app or two for which I want a "Reset all settings" button.

I have noticed as of Yosemite or so, defaults are cached in some strange ways by OS X and from the terminal executing a defaults delete `com.mycompany.myapp` does not work consistently at all. I usually also need to issue a `defaults write com.mycompany.app dummy dummy`

I suspect this has largely to do with SandBoxing...

I want to reliably implement resetting defaults, as well as cleaning up my sandbox and cache directories.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this from within the same app whose settings you want to reset, try:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```